# PHP: How to change value on validation in SQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, forms, validation

I have this code

```
<form action="" method="POST">
PIN: 
<input type="text" name="pin"><br />
E-Mail: 
<input type="text" name="email"><br />  
<input type="submit" value="Claim" name="submit" />
</form>


<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

if(!empty($_POST['pin']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
$pin=$_POST['pin'];
$email=$_POST['email'];


$con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','admin') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('user_codevalidation') or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="INSERT INTO codes(email) VALUES('$email') WHERE pin='".$dbpin."'";
mysql_query($sql);
echo "Successfully claimed!";
{
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
$dbpin=$row['pin'];
}

if($pin == $dbpin)
{
$sql="INSERT INTO codes(email,claimed) VALUES('$email','1') WHERE pin = $dbpin";
echo "Successfully claimed!";
}
} else {
echo "Invalid pin or it has already been claimed once!";
}

} else {
echo "All fields are required!";
}
}
?>
```

I want to be able to validate `pin` AND if claimed = 0 in the database in the row `$pin` where `pin` is equal to the value in pin textbox `$pin`, if it is equal, then execute `$sql` which is to insert the value in email into the sql `$email` which is the email textbox, and then change the `claimed` value to '1' which is by default 0 in the database.

I got everything working and it says 'Successfully claimed!' but it does not change my values in the database. Please help!

Edit: I have added the execute MySQL query and it still gives me the same result!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no query execution command mysql_query()
Add this line after the query

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to execute the query

**Edit**
I added some lines in order to debug your query. Please copy & paste and tell me if you see any error.

PIN: 

E-Mail:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    if(!empty($_POST['pin']) && !empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $pin=$_POST['pin'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];

        $con=mysql_connect('localhost','root','admin') or die(mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db('user_codevalidation') or die("cannot select DB");

        $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM codes WHERE pin='".$pin."'");
        $numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
        if($numrows!=0)
        {
            while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
            {
                $dbpin=$row['pin'];
            }

            if($pin == $dbpin)
            {
                $sql="INSERT INTO codes(email,claimed) VALUES('".$email."','1') WHERE pin = '".$dbpin."'";
                $res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
                echo "Successfully claimed!";
            }
        } else {
            echo "Invalid pin or it has already been claimed once!";
        }

    } else {
        echo "All fields are required!";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: hi i have changed that and it still does not execute it and does not change the values in my database.

Comment: here is my code now which still gives me the same result                                                  `$sql="INSERT INTO codes(email) VALUES('$email') WHERE pin='".$dbpin."'";
 mysql_query($sql);
 echo "Successfully claimed!";`

Comment: Hi I got this error, `Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\couponreg\login.php on line 27
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE pin = '0000'' at line 1`

Comment: well... there you go. fix that! try with removing the single quotes '

Comment: Hi, still get the same error without the single quotes now..... `Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\couponreg\login.php on line 27
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE pin = 0000' at line 1`

Comment: paste this echo $sql;  before the $res line

Comment: `Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\couponreg\login.php on line 27
INSERT INTO codes(email,claimed) VALUES('tynujnuy','1') WHERE pin = 0000You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE pin = 0000' at line 1` is there any errors?

Comment: I actually want to insert the email and claimed data into the row the `pin` was entered, do you think it is correct to use `WHERE pin = $dbpin`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you execute the query:

```
mysql_query($sql);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php